# How do I insert an alpha symbol using ggplot annotate?

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, lyx

I have plot a graph using ggplot2 and am using knitr within Lyx. 
I am trying to place a label  in the plot and am using the annotate command:

```
ggplot() + annotate("text",y=10,x=0,label="\u3B1",vjust=-1,size = 6)
```

I believe \u3B1 will generate the greek `alpha` symbol. Unfortunately this only generates a normal lower case `a`.

How do I get the symbol I require to appear?

Comment: Your code works for me, but as an alt you could try `ggplot() + 
   annotate("text",y=0.5, x=0.5,label="~alpha",vjust=-1,size = 6, parse=TRUE)`. If this also doesn't work you should add you system details to your question.

Comment: Works for me as well, are you sure it's not printing the right character? As lowercase alpha does look very similar to "a"